# Integrating Factor and $\frac{dy}{dx}+y=3x$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, solution-verification, integrating-factor

$\newcommand{\diff}{\frac{dy}{dx}}$

> I was given the following problem:
>   $$\diff+y = e^{3x}$$

**My approach**

The integrating factor I found to be $P(x)=1$. Then my method to tackle the problem resulted in the following: $$e^{\int P(x)dx}=e^{\int 1dx}=e^x$$

I began to end the problem in these steps:
$$
\begin{align}
\diff+y &= e^{3x} \\
e^x\diff+e^xy &= e^{4x} \\
\diff\left[e^xy\right] &= e^{4x} \\
\int\diff\left[e^xy\right]dx &= \int e^{4x}dx \\
e^xy &= \frac{1}4e^{4x}+C \\
y &= \frac{1}4e^{3x}+Ce^{-x}
\end{align}$$

Is my result correct?

Comment: Your result looks correct; you could always check by plugging it in and making sure it satisfies the equation

Comment: Whoever downvoted, could they please explain the downvote for my education? I found this to be a well-put post and upvoted.

Comment: @gt6989b as the OP I don't dude I have been using stack since highschool, and key rule I learned even with change of moderators if its homework show work which I do there is like not a problem i don't show work for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks good to me. For the future, note a couple of sanity checks:

- it satisfies the original equation
- your equation is linear and 1st degree, so I expect one family of solutions ($Ce^{-x}$ here) and one particular solution $e^{3x}/4$ here

You did make a typo on the first step writing a $-$ instead of a $+$, but you followed by using $+$ instead of $-$...